# What will be the css of this input field?

Tags: css, html

i have an input field saying enter your name, i want to add CSS settings that when i click in the field *"enter you name"* disappears.

when i click out of it, if i haven't entered any thing *"enter your name"* comes back.

what will be the solution for this problem? is it CSS only ? or JavaScript?

Comment: Use JavaScript for that.

Comment: Go with Javascript `focus` and `blur` events!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use this

```
<input type="text" value="Enter Your Name" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Enter Your Name') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Enter Your Name';}">
```

Hope its help

Answer (score 2):

If you use the `html5` doctype in your pages, this is easy

`<input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="Enter your name">`

Use the `placeholder` attribute and any modern browser will do the rest.

If the browser does not support the `placeholder` attribute, you will need to use javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at the HTML5 `placeholder` [attribute](http://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder)?

Answer (score 2):

try this one:

```
<input name="textfield1" type="text" class="login_te" value="enter you name" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='enter you name';" onfocus="if(this.value=='enter you name')this.value='';" />
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to use javascript:

```
<input type="text" value="Click..." onfocus="if(this.value == 'Click...')this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value == '')this.value='Click...';" />
```

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood your question, you want to hide the whole input box.
You have to use javascript in combination with css.

```
document.getElementById("id").style.display = "none";
```

will hide the div that contains your input field

```
document.getElementById("id").style.display = "block";
```

will show your div again.
All you have to do is copy these two snipplets into the javascript events you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, that's done with JavaScript, but if you're against using JavaScript, you could use a background image that says "Enter your name", and have it disappear when the field is focused.

```
input#namefield {
    background: url(enter_your_name.png);
}

input#namefield:focus {
    background-image: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a CSS thing

You can simply use :

```
<input type="text" value="Enter Your Name" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Enter Your Name') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Enter Your Name';}">
```

If you're designing for modern browsers that support HTML5 you could simply use something like this :

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Name" />
```

This way when they field is focused the text will disappear

Now to make it work for older browsers you could use [this jQuery plugin called HTML5 Forms](http://www.matiasmancini.com.ar/jquery-plugin-ajax-form-validation-html5.html). It also add a support a lot of HTML5 forms on older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`placeholder` attribute](http://developers.whatwg.org/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-placeholder-attribute).

Unfortunately, it's not supported in every browser.

So, you must use a JavaScript fallback to make it work in those browsers. I recommend this one:

https://github.com/mathiasbynens/Placeholder-jQuery-Plugin

Take a look at the demo in a browser that does support `placeholder` such as Chrome, and then in a browser that does not such as IE9:

http://mathiasbynens.be/demo/placeholder